# How can I see if termcap or terminfo was used and how to change between them?

Tags: terminal, termcap, terminfo

When I login to a remote machine (Debian Wheezy in my case) using SSH with Putty (in my case with default `xterm`), how can I check if the terminal defintion from `termcap` or from `terminfo` was used? What to do if I want to use the other one by default accordingly (I have root rights)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, we have a couple bad assumptions to overcome here. Firstly both terminfo and termcap provide mappings between desired functionality and terminal control commands for multiple terminals. for example they answer the question how do I clear the screen on a televideo 922.

Secondly they are not used on a per session or per machine basis, they are used on a per application basis. What this means on a practical basis is that although you can tell if either library was used (`ldd` works great on dynamically linked libraries, or you can use `strace`/`truss`/… to see what files the program loads) and change which was used (source code modifications or wrapper libraries) in most cases it is not worth bothering with and much simpler just to make sure you have both databases installed for your terminal. this will work just fine since both use the TERM environment variable.

Specifically there is no default (aside from distribution policy but most use both).

If you were wanting to write an application that uses both, that is certainly possible but off topic fo U&L, instead ask on stack overflow.